# How to Load data from multiple OLEDB sources (1000 approx) to 1 OLEDB destination dynamically in SSIS

Tags: mysql

I have to load data from 1000 databases in one SQL instance to 1 database in another SQL instance. Each of the 1000 databases has around 50 tables with the exact same schema. The destination database also has the same 50 tables with the exact schema. The Data only for the current date needs to be loaded.

Now the challenge here is to make the data load dynamic. Even though the number of databases or the number of tables increase, the design of the package should not change.

can anyone please suggest a way to accomplish this without creating 1000 OLEDB datasources?

Thanks in advance.